# Acess denied for connection to MySQL DB using XAMPP on Windows 10

Tags: php, mysqli, xampp

I created database called "users" and tried to connect to it with PHP, but I get access denied.

Here is the message I get:

> "Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user
>   ''@'localhost' to database 'users' in
>   D:\XAMP\htdocs\telepol\formProcess.php on line 8

Connection failed: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'users'"

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbName = "users";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";

?>
```

Comment: `$username = "root";` thats the defualt mysql user on your localhost

Comment: which php version use you?? try this mysqli_connect() function

Comment: The reason its not connecting you did not specify the user

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile that was the reason I tought the default username should be empty string " ". Thank you.

Add your comment as an answer, so I can give you credit.

Comment: @BlackSova no man there's no need to give me credit for such, that was just a silly mistake u did

Comment: you can select @A.ANoman 's answer

Comment: @A.ANoman why should he try `mysqli_connect() ` thats procedural and he's using OO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a silly mistake..

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root"; // This is mistake 
$password = "";
$dbName = "users";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Adding users to [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-users.html)

You need grant privileges to the user if you want external access to database(ie. web pages).

Answer (score 0):

In Xampp I noticed that when I created a new user, the default host field for 'all host' access was listed as '%' -- changing the access to 'localhost' allowed my non-root user to connect properly, whereas the % did not. This was uing the built-in phpmyadmin tool.